# Don't display spaces and tabulation on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My VS2010 display special char like spaces and tab (http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b012877709a28970c-pi).

I'd like disable it. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit -> Advanced -> View White Space

Keyboard shortcut is Ctrl+R, Ctrl+W